# Identify each drawn path in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to identify each drawing.

For example after I draw an object I want that object to have the propriety name = "My Drawing 1" so I can easily refer to it later by

```
canvas.getObjectByName('My Drawing Name');
```

getObjectByName function

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getItemByName = function(name) {
    var object = null, objects = this.getObjects();

    for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (objects[i].name && objects[i].name === name) {
            object = objects[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return object;
};
```

The code that activates drawing function:

```
         canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

         var img = $("#patternImg")[0];

         var texturePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
         texturePatternBrush.source = img;
         texturePatternBrush.selectable = true;
         texturePatternBrush.name = img.getAttribute("data-name");

         canvas.freeDrawingBrush = texturePatternBrush;
         canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = img.getAttribute("data-height");
```

Using the code above I can check if can verify if a drawing exists by:

```
 fabric.Canvas.prototype.getDrawByName = function(name) {
    var object = null, objects = this.getObjects();

    for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
        if (objects[i].canvas.freeDrawingBrush.name && objects[i].canvas.freeDrawingBrush.name === name) {
            object = objects[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return object;
};
```

The problem is each time I am drawing an object that has another name canvas.FreeDrawingBrush.name will be the same for each object on my canvas.

I am not so familiar with FabricJS and I don't even know if what I am trying to do is even possible. At least I made myself clear what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the `canvas` property of a `fabric.Object`, you are simply getting a reference to the `fabric.Canvas` element that this object is rendered on. The `freeDrawingBrush` property of this `fabric.Canvas` element will always be the current free drawing brush.

Instead, I would set this `name` property onto each individual object, when it is done drawing. (This could be when you exit from drawing mode, or perhaps right before you switch to a different brush) using `fabric.Object.set` method.

Doing it this way, you aren't relying on an object's `canvas` property in any way.